# Everything is blurry in the viewport and when it's rendering

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

I rendered the scene. I used Denoising to remove noise. Everything was rendered clearly, then something happened. Now everything is blurry in the viewport and when it's rendering.

I reset the settings to the factory settings, and then even deleted the folder with user information - nothing helped. Everything is blurry.

What i should do?

P.s  changing the number of samples, nothing changes[image]

Comment: What happens if you un-check (disable) the Viewport Denoising box (It's enabled in your image)?

Comment: Previously, it worked and did not blur the picture - it just removed the noise. And now he blurs. Without Denoising, everything is in noise. Added Denoising in the compositing tab, the situation is the same. Everything blurs, instead of removing the noise

Comment: Disable denoising. Denoising will make the image blurrier, specially if the sample count is low.

Comment: https://yadi.sk/i/h9ykebOWOY671Q I made this render before with Denoising

Comment: But now ( I don't know why) it doesn't work